# How can I extract the biased exponent from a floating point number in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, exponent

I am having issues finding the biased exponent from a floating point number. I do not understand why I return a 0 from any number that I enter for the parameter. Here is my code:

```
iFloat_t floatGetExp(iFloat_t x)
{
    return ((x >> 23) & 0x7f800000);
}
```

The exponent of a float is from bits to 23-30, so that is why I am shifting to the right by 23 and have a mask of `0x7f800000`.
For example, if I passed it a float of `248.875`, the exponent should be 22.

Comment: You are masking the wrong bits, after shifting 23 bits there will be nothing in those bit positions, and you destroy the result of the shift. How can you expect a value of 22 when you have masked off bits 0..23 after the shift?

Comment: Oh, so how do I go about properly masking? Do I mask before the shift?

Comment: Your mask is for the value _before_ the shift, not after. So, `((x & 0x7f800000) > 23)`, or, better yet, `((x >> 23) & 0xff)` Either will work, but the latter seems simpler and easier to understand [IMO]

Comment: Do you need to mask at all, apart from the sign bit?

Comment: @WeatherVane sign bit is MSB, so mask is required to isolate the exponent. Otherwise, the shift produces `sgn,exp` instead of just `exp`

Comment: @CraigEstey I thought I said that the sign bit must be masked. The mantissa bits will be shifted out, and if the value is unsigned, then `0` bits are shifted in from the left.

Comment: I switched my code to ((x >> 23) & 0xff), yet the biased exponent returned was still 0.

Answer (score 4):

`((x >> 23) & 0x7f800000);` is shift and masking in the wrong order.

---

The math library, C has a function that retrieves the exponent.  This is the *portable* way.

```
int floatGetExp(float x) {
    int expo;
    frexpf(x, &expo);  // fetch exponent  (0.5 <= significand < 1.0) * 2^expo
    if (x) expo -= 1;
    return expo;
}
```

Assuming [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) format for `iFloat_t x` there are 4 cases to consider:

Infinity/NaN, normal numbers, sub-normals, zero.

```
iFloat_t floatGetExp(iFloat_t x) {
  uint32_t u = (uint32_t) x; // move into known type
  // mask off the biased exponent 
  int bias_expo = (u & 0x7F800000) >> 23;
  if (bias_exp == 0xFF) return TBD;  // inf or NaN
  if (bias_exp > 0) return bias_exp - 127; // the usual
  // handle sub-normal numbers
  if (u & 0x7FFFFFFF == 0) return 0; // zero
  bias_exp -= 126;
  while (u & 0x00400000 == 0) {
    u <<= 1;
    bias_exp--;
  }
  return bias_exp;
}
```

Comment: `if (x) expo - 1;` does nothing. I'm not sure what it was intended for but no line of code that I can see one typo from it makes the result the IEEE 754 exponent.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Yes `expo - 1` should have been `expo -= 1`.  When `x == 0` the exponent is irrelevant. and 0 is a common acceptable result. - as with `frexpf()`  When `x != 0`, the exponent derived from `frexpf()` is off-by-one as that has the significand in the range of [.5, 1.0) and many want the exponent matching a significand in the range of [1.0, 2.0) .